# How do I get the merge list with git?

Tags: git

When I try to merge a file, I get

```
$ git merge origin/develop
Removing t/table_statistic_grains_test.t
Removing t/table_statistic_grains_calllog.t
Removing t/table_statistic_grains_accession.t
Auto-merging t/table_donor_document.t
Auto-merging install.sh
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in install.sh
```

However, when I lose that that list and I try to finish the merge all I get is,

```
$ git merge
error: 'merge' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree,
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,
hint: or use 'git commit -a'.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

How do I get that list back without `--abort` and an attempt to re`merge`?

Comment: Wouldn't checking `git status` help identifying the conflicted files? Or `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`?

Answer (score 0):

Use git mergetool on "install.sh" file or edit it in your editor to try merge file manually.
After that you should add merged file to index and commit it.
Now you should have opportunity to do other things.

```
git mergetool install.sh
git add install.sh
git commit -a
```